# How to manage Dynamic UITableviewCell Height it is contained Dynamic UITableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am trying to add dynamic UITableView inside UITableViewCell, but i am unable to manage height of cell. please assist me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Asssign class to tableView

```
import UIKit

class DynamicHeightTableView: UITableView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if bounds.size != intrinsicContentSize {
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        print(contentSize.height)
        return contentSize
    }
    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet{
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }
    
    override func reloadData() {
        super.reloadData()
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
    
}
```

Like mentioned in Image

[image]

Reload Cell TableView after fetching or assigning data to the table view.
Also call the main controller tableView.reload() by delegate or locacal notification, after cell.tableView.reload()

Cell tableView

```
  cell.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
  cell.tableView.reloadData()
  cell.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

main Controller tableView

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```